# binding datagridview to [Browsable(false)] columns

Tags: .net, winforms, binding, .net-3.5, datagridview

I have a a datagrid that I am binding to class that has some columns marked `[Browsable(false)]`. These columns are showing up blank. Is there some way to turn this off.

I am not using any autobinding but creating the columns myself and setting the DataPropertyName property.

It took me a really long time to find why they are blank now I'm hoping there is some easy way to show the values in them. The only thing I can think of is to write my own DataGridViewColumn classes and re-implement the binding. Any other ideas?

Here is some code that demonstrates the problem, GridBrowsableProblem is a new form with a DataGridView dropped onto it. When run ProblemProperty has no value.

```
public partial class GridBrowsableProblem : Form
{
    public class ProblemTestClass
    {
        [Browsable(false)]
        public string ProblemProperty { get; set; }

        public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public GridBrowsableProblem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column1.DataPropertyName = "ProblemProperty";

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column2.DataPropertyName = "AnotherProperty";

        ProblemTestClass item = new ProblemTestClass();
        item.ProblemProperty = "test1";
        item.AnotherProperty = "test2";

        BindingList<ProblemTestClass> bindingList = new BindingList<ProblemTestClass>();
        bindingList.Add(item);

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column1);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column2);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingList;
    }
}
```

Comment: some code will help, columns code...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [Browsable(false)] attribute or set it to true.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.browsableattributes(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.browsableattributes%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)